# Firewall settings in a Gitlab Docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab, iptables, ufw

I am running GitLab in a Docker container and wanted to configure https following [these instructions](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-1804/). To do this, I invoked the terminal with the following command in Powershell:

```
docker exec -ti -u root b836c4cdfd37 bash
```

After entering the command `sudo ufw allow https`, the following error message is displayed:

```
WARN: initcaps
[Errno 2] iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Maybe iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)
```

How can I execute the sudo ufw allow https command without errors?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions you are following are for installing GitLab directly on an Ubuntu host, not running GitLab inside of a docker container, which requires a different set of installation and networking steps. In your scenario, `ufw` will not work as described in the guide you're following because docker manages the networking for your container by default. Docker's networking can interfere with trying to manage your firewall configuration with `ufw` or `iptables`. Even if you manage to get the command to work, you'll find that docker's network management can [bypass your ufw configurations](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22054) in your container anyhow.

To install GitLab in docker, you should follow [the official docker installation instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html). You can also review all the other [installation methods](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/install_methods.html) for GitLab for additional context.

If you really want to continue installing gitlab "manually" inside of a container, just skip the UFW steps and make sure you have configured port mapping for the GitLab container from the docker host (e.g. to map http/https, `docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 ...`).